# FileField Sources module not working

Tags: 7

I have installed FileField Sources module. I am using "Remote URL" option for file Upload. While adding content when I am giving the image url say "http://www.abc.com/test.png", the file is not getting transfered.Instead it is not showing up anything.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: are you sure if have access to the file at the remote URL?

Comment: Yes. I am able to open the link directly and able to save the image to my local system.

Comment: do you get any error?

Comment: No, I didn't get any error. When I saved the content type even content type is not getting saved when remote url is speficied. Without remote url content type is getting saved properly.

Comment: I think the you are trying to get the URL from the site on localhost, which might not work; this is similar to the problem updating modules from UI on a localhost site.

Comment: No, I am using the URL on internet.